# Как лучше организовать просмотр данных?

Tags: android, ui

Разрабатываю приложение для просмотра новостей с сайта. Серверная часть предоставляет `REST API`  У нас есть 3 сайта, в которых 8-10 разных категорий.
Я делаю запрос к серваку, получаю данные и на данный момент отображаю данные в 
 На данный момент реализовано все через `NavigationView`.

В `NavigationDrawer` у нас список с сайтами. При нажатии на элемент в Tablayout грузятся все категории данного сайта. При скроллинге вниз данные догружаются в `RecyclerView`. Я сперва думал что это оптимальный метод отображения данных, но начинает местами тормозить скроллинг и память кушает норм. Если прогрузить данные вниз на 100-200 данных уже некомфортно работать. И это только если я гружу данные в одном Табе. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня изначально была версия без табов, одно `Activity` в котором я просматривал данные. Все шустро работало. Правда и сайт был только один
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И в принципе, я хочу отказаться от табов в пользу данного вида отображения. В голове даже промелькнула идея сделать Treelist в NavigationDrawer, но как то убого это все смотрится))) 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В общем идеи кончились. Буду благодарен за совет.

Comment: Скорей всего вы храните все новости в памяти, что соответственно и ведет к ее использованию. Если это так, то попробуйте сохранять новости в бд, и уже оттуда их отображать. И еще покажите код, т.к. по картинкам не возможно определить почему тормозит ваше приложение.